# identifying words in file 1 and matching them to second file and printing them

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, awk

I have two files as follows 
     File 1 has list of Ids

```
ram
Tarah
taikah
jhdfklj
```

File 2 has

```
id=ram;*between*hkjhdswklf     kjsdklhglshglkhgklsdgkhdfg
id=taikah;jhdjfkhg**kjdfkjksfdjk dfkjskdfjkljdflkjsdflj
```

Basically i want to match Ids from file 1 to file 2 and paste the complete line of file 2

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Awk was designed for this (here with GNU `awk` for the capturing of brace matched patterns into an array in `match()`):

```
$ awk '
    NR == FNR { Ids[$1]++; next; }
    match($1, /id=([^;]+);/, Id) && Id[1] in Ids
' /file1 /file2
id=ram;*between*hkjhdswklf     kjsdklhglshglkhgklsdgkhdfg
id=taikah;jhdjfkhg**kjdfkjksfdjk dfkjskdfjkljdflkjsdflj
```

Several of the alternate responses propose solutions which make various assumptions about the input which are not exactly evident in the sample given by OP. One thing that *is* clear, though, is that there is a legitimate word in the data following `id=xxx;`, so it's not safe to assume that one of the ids from `File 1` might not be somewhere in the data as well.

This is why Awk is much better than [`fgrep(1)`](/a/119856). Awk will break up the input into fields which can limit the possible match, which has been done in the example above by specifying that the match must be in the first field (`$1`).

The example input contains some data right next to the id, so if you wanted an absolute bullet-proof way of matching the ids in `File 1`, you could define the field separator (`FS`) as `;` and only print if there is an exact match.

Assume `File 2` contains:

```
id=ram;*between*hkjhdswklf     kjsdklhglshglkhgklsdgkhdfg
id=taikah;jhdjfkhg**kjdfkjksfdjk dfkjskdfjkljdflkjsdflj
id=notinlist;jhdjfkhg**kjdfkjksfdjk ram*dfkjskdfjkljdflkjsdflj
id=notinlist;*between*taikah*hkjhdswklf     kjsdklhglshglkhgklsdgkhdfg
```

Then the following will still work

```
$ awk -v FS=";" '
    NR == FNR {Id = "id=" $0; Ids[Id]++; next; }
    $1 in Ids
' /file1 /file2
id=ram;*between*hkjhdswklf     kjsdklhglshglkhgklsdgkhdfg
id=taikah;jhdjfkhg**kjdfkjksfdjk dfkjskdfjkljdflkjsdflj
```

Note that [the other Awk solution](/a/119824) will be very slow for large files since it is O(N<sup>2</sup>). The [`sed` version](/a/119806) will work, but personally, I find `sed` to be unreadable for mere mortals.

Comment: May not work if there is more than one `id=xxx;` per line.

Comment: There are probably dozens of cases where it _might_ not work, but those cases are not specified in the question nor in the sample input. So absent more than one `id=xxx;` _in the first field_, then it will work as intended with the sample provided. It's the poster's responsibility to provide representative input.

Comment: That was not intended as a negative critique on your answer, I was the 1st to upvote your answer and it most certainly fits the OP's need. Just a comment indicating a limitation for anyone coming here with a similar need (which is what SE is about)

Answer (score 3):

That is exactly what `fgrep(1)` was created for... or more modernly (may use GNU exensions):

```
grep -Fwf file1 file2
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```

Comment: This. We were all wrong.

Comment: Not quite: this will also match e.g. `id=baram` if `file1` contains `tam`. See Stephane's answer for how do handle this.

Comment: @Gilles not with `grep -Fwf file1 file2`.

Answer (score 2):

Another convoluted `sed` one:

```
echo | sed -e '1,/^$/{H;d;}
               G;/id=\([^;]\{1,\}\);.*\n\1\n/!d
               s/\n.*//' file1 - file2
```

A POSIX version of [myq's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119802/22565), with the same limitation:

```
awk '
  NR == FNR { Ids[$1]++; next; }
  match($0, /id=[^;]+/) && substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-3) in Ids
' file1 file2
```

An approach using `grep`:

```
sed 's/.*/id=&;/' file1 | grep -Ff - file2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$0]=$0;next}{for(id in ids){if($0 ~ id){print}}}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    sed -rfn - <<-HD ./file2
        $(sed -r 's|.*|s/id=&/\&/p|' ./file1)
    HD
```

This works. It first reads only `file1` in and transforms each of its lines into a `sed` regular expression for `file2`, `w`riting each of those lines to its `stdout` which happens to be the subshell run in the here-document assigned to the second `sed`'s file-descriptor `<<-HD` 0. So `sed` invocation the second pulls in `sed` the first's output as its regex pattern from `- stdin`. Its script looks like this:

```
    s/id=ram/&/p
    s/id=Tarah/&/p
    s/id=taikah/&/p
```

The above is the script the second `sed` invocation runs. Because *every* line in `file1` is transformed into a literal *id=** match for `file2` without relying on any reference address before the `i` in `id` or after the following `;semicolon`; I don't think it could *miss* anything, and should (hopefully now) be very easy to alter to handle any variations on the original need as necessary.

And when `sed` two is through, the output looks like this:

```
    id=ram;*between*hkjhdswklf     kjsdklhglshglkhgklsdgkhdfg
    id=taikah;jhdjfkhg**kjdfkjksfdjk dfkjskdfjkljdflkjsdflj
```

P.S. If you want a good laugh, have a look at the edit history on this answer - my path to this solution was more than just a little convoluted - it was a trainwreck.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas : I know - had to rewrite the whole command. It was awful. It's better now though. I did have some experience with 'R' just the other day - but it was different in that the lines were literally 1 for 1 collated. Also, I think it was eating my `|pipe` anyway, so it was easier to do the processing through twice - still streamed - but end to end to end again, if you take my meaning. And that's why the working command just pulls them in together and deletes the first file's lines from the pattern space after writing them out to the pattern file.